# How to display two links over an Image onmouseover event?

Tags: html, css, onmouseover

I need to display two links to another page while hovering over the image as shown below

[image]

I had achieved this using some CSS and Java script, But i found that this is not the efficient way to do it, especially my java script is causing some loops, what i had done so far is:

**Java-Script:**

```
function showitems(){
if(document.getElementById('divsub1').style.display=="block"){
    document.getElementById('divsub1').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('divsub2').style.display="none";
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('divsub1').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('divsub2').style.display="block";
    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.mainimage{
background-color: #CC6633;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
}
.divsub1{
display: none;
position: absolute;
float: left;
width: 50px;
height: 20px;
margin-top: -30px;
margin-left: 10px
}
.divsub2{
display: none;
position: absolute;
float: left;
width: 30px;
height: 20px;
margin-top: -30px;
margin-left: 160px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="1"><img src="56.jpg" class="mainimage" id="mainimage" onmouseover="showitems()" onmouseout="showitems()"/></a>
<div class="divsub1" onmouseover="showitems()" onmouseout="showitems()" id="divsub1"><a href="2">link1</a> </div>
<div class="divsub2" onmouseover="showitems()" onmouseout="showitems()" id="divsub2"><a href="3">link2</a></div>
```

Im sure that this is the not the best approach, and i don't have too much experience in CSS, awaiting comments!!

Comment: Seems to work. What's your question?

Comment: @j08691 but im having problems while hovering over the link sections, i observed it as :: calling the function showitems() multiple times , since i invoked the function on mouseover and mouseout events of divsub1 & divsub2 !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple. Just enclose your image in another div, let's call it **main-div** and put this code in css.

```
#main-div:hover>#divsub1,
#main-div:hover>#divsub2{

display:block;
}
```

Here is the result http://jsfiddle.net/xejmq48r/

No need to use any kind of Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

If possible, move the links inside a parent. The css becomes much easier:

```
<div href="1" class="outer">
  <img src="56.jpg" class="mainimage" id="mainimage" />
  <a href="2">link1</a>
  <a href="3">link2</a>
</div>


.outer .inner{ display: none; }
.outer:hover .inner{
   display: block;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, But this breaks the nesting rules!! <a > tag must be properly closed.

Comment: Right, you would want it in a div. Same answer as YourFriend. Edited answer.